# Why can't I offer a bounty of less than 500 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I wanted to start two other bounties [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133031/is-there-a-non-commutative-ring-with-a-trivial-automorphism-group) because "one or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty." However, the only possible amount of reputation I can offer is 500, which seems unfair given that the first bounty for the answer I found the best was only 300. Can I do something about it?

[image]

A feature request related to this question is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/giving-a-bounty-to-several-answers-at-once).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/):

> To prevent “infinite” bounty periods, multiple bounties started on the same question by the same user double in cost every time. So if the first bounty is 50 rep, the next will be 100, then 200, then 400, then the maximum.

By design if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the subsequent one must cost at least twice as much as the previous one.

Comment: That's a pity... I think it's unfair to the other answerers. There is an answer very similar to the one I awarded the bounty to and pretty much just as good. But not better. There seems to be no way to treat the answerers fairly.

Comment: you may want to comment upon [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users), especially the answer suggested by Popular Demand. (You may also consider opening a feature request for this.)

Comment: Thanks, I've posted a comment there. As for a feature request, I'm not sure what feature I'd like to request. Do you think it is likely for the SE team to remove this limitation altogether? I don't understand why there shouldn't be "infinite" bounty periods, but if it's a valid reason, then my problem may not outweigh it, right?

Comment: @ymar: but perhaps the ability to split the bounty among several users? or the ability to directly dole out another chunk of the same bounty to another answerer (say I open a bounty of 150. two answers equally good came in. I get to choose to award 150 to either one _or_ I get to put up immediately another 150 to give 150 to both.) This latter one would (a) allow a/all good answer(s) to get the bounty promised and (b) not affect the "infinite bounty" problem at all.

Comment: I like the second idea. The first one seems unfair in my case -- both posts contain full, detailed answers to my question. If I put a price of 300 rep for doing this, then the answerers shouldn't be getting 150 apiece.